# How to fix splash screen white screen issue?

Tags: ionic3

I have a "problem" with my app. When it's running, after the splash screen and before the app it's ready, a white screen appears for about 20 seconds and it's so annoying. How is it possible to avoid this white screen in ionic 3?

Comment: how are you building your app?

Comment: I am frsher. i can't understant your question.plz ask clearly...

Comment: How are you testing your app? With a real device or an emulator? And how did the app get to your device? If you are using the command-line which command did you use?

Comment: ionic cordova run android --device

Comment: try 
ionic cordova run android --prod --device

Comment: I used  this cmd running taken long time....
Running app-scripts build: --prod --platform android --target cordova
[18:50:43]  build prod started ...
[18:50:43]  clean started ...
[18:50:43]  clean finished in 6 ms
[18:50:43]  copy started ...
[18:50:43]  deeplinks started ...
[18:50:43]  deeplinks finished in 201 ms
[18:50:43]  ngc started ...
[18:51:02]  ngc finished in 19.36 s
[18:51:02]  preprocess started ...
[18:51:02]  preprocess finished in 1 ms
[18:51:02]  webpack started ...
[18:51:03]  copy finished in 20.13 s

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000" />
```